# Reversible Logic Circuit Synthesis

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, circuit-families, project-topic

I am about to choose a project regarding "Reversible logic circuit synthesis". I've studied well about "Switching circuits and Logic design" and I found it very intriguing but I've got no idea about the other topic. Can someone please elaborate it and explain what it refers or point some sources. Thank you guys in advance. :)

Comment: I would rephrase the question to be more research oriented: What is "reversible logic circuit synthesis"? What are good introductory texts on it? I am familiar with switching circuits and logic design, how does this latter topic relates to the former?

Comment: You might also want to read about *Reversible Programming Languages*.

Comment: This is an unfocused project/thesis topic question. Closed based on [this policy](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/802/policy-questions-about-topic-for-research-project/). Please refer to the policy, the question can be reopened if it is improved s.t. it becomes more focused. Please also read the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with the field, but my advisor [Shigeru Yamashita](http://www.ngc.is.ritsumei.ac.jp/~ger/index-e.html) is. I recommend you to check his home page. Here are some interesting papers he has:

1. [A transduction-based framework to synthesize RSFQ circuits](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1118299.1118368). Shigeru Yamashita, Katsunori Tanaka, Hideyuki Takada, Koji Obata, Kazuyoshi Takagi. In ASP-DAC 2006.
2. [Transformation rules for designing CNOT-based quantum circuits](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=513918.514026). Kazuo Iwama, Yahiko Kambayashi, Shigeru Yamashita. DAC 2002.
3. [DDMF: An Efficient Decision Diagram Structure for Design Verification of Quantum Circuits under a Practical Restriction](http://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/transfun/E91.A/12/E91.A_3793/_article). Shigeru YAMASHITA, Shin-ichi MINATO and D. Michael MILLER. IEICE Transactions on Fundamentals of Electronics, Communications and Computer Sciences E91.A (2008) , No. 12 pp.3793-3802.

Other people that you should check their home pages are [Igor Markov](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~imarkov/) and [Dimitri Maslov](http://www.iqc.ca/~dmaslov/).

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on the topic.

Googling "reversible logic circuit synthesis" spews up a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0207001) with the same title, by Shende et al., although in the quantum computing setting.

However, page 3 of the paper contains a short review on classical reversible circuits, which points at better sources of information.